# Reference request: from a reduced expression of an element in a Coxeter group to another reduced expression

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, coxeter-groups

Are there some references which proves the following result?

Let $W$ be a Coxeter group and $w \in W$. Then different reduced expressions of $w$ can be transformed from one into anther using only the braid relations.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is also known as [Matsumoto's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsumoto%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).
It was also independently proved by Jacques Tits.

There are tons of books having proofs of this, e.g. Theorem 3.3.1 in "Combinatorics of Coxeter" groups by Björner and Brenti. I am sure it's also in "Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups" by Humphreys, but I don't have it at hand to give a precise reference.

Comment: Actually, I didn't deal with the combinatorial questions so explicitly in my book though I did discuss briefly the approach by Tits http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0254129 to the word problem in 8.1 (following a short remark on a less attractive method at the end of Chapter 5).    While Matsumoto built on early work (of Iwahori. Tits) dealing with generators and relations, he didn't address the word problem for a Coxeter group as such.   At any rate, the best exposition is in section 3.3-3.4 of the Bjorner-Brenti text.

Answer (score 2):

[George Lusztig, *Hecke algebras with unequal parameters*, arXiv:math/0208154v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208154v2), Theorem 1.9.